# Determining Paused State of Quartz Trigger?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Is there a way to determine if a specific Trigger in Quartz is in paused state?

I know of the getPausedTriggerGroups() method on Scheduler, but there doesn't seem to be a way to figure out the paused state of a particular Trigger for a particular JobDetail.

Any friendly suggestions?

Comment: This question is in reference to Quartz version 1.8.1.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the API docs, Scheduler.getTriggerState(String triggerName, String triggerGroup) can tell you the state of a particular trigger, returning one of these constants:
    Trigger.STATE_NORMAL, **Trigger.STATE_PAUSED**, Trigger.STATE_COMPLETE, Trigger.STATE_ERROR, Trigger.STATE_BLOCKED, Trigger.STATE_NONE

But, yeah, that's not entirely intuitive.  :)

Comment: Well, there you go.  I completely over looked that method on Scheduler.  I figured that state wasn't being stored in the Trigger object itself, and tried looking at the methods on Scheduler, but just missed it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Beyond Quartz 1.8.1 this is an enumeration.  See import org.quartz.Trigger.TriggerState;